# How can you set the upload interval of the TSDB blocks in Thanos sidecar?

Tags: kube-prometheus-stack, thanos

We are using the kube-prometheus-stack deploying Prometheus together with Thanos. The Thanos-Sidecar uploads TSDB blocks to an object storage bucket as Prometheus produces them every 2 hours.  This is the default behaviour.

In the helm-chart I set "disableCompation" to true which is already done if you use Thanos.

```
prometheusSpec:
    ## If true, pass --storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=2h to prometheus. This is already done if using Thanos
    ##
    disableCompaction: true
```

Is there an option to set the block-duration to another value than two hours?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two params for prometheus and keep them same so compaction does not happen.

```
--storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=2h
--storage.tsdb.min-block-duration=2h
```